# How to keep a teething puppy from biting me and other people?

Tags: dogs, behavior, training, safety, biting

I have a 9 week old pit bull puppy. He is teething for the first time. I have given him chew toys but if someone goes to pet him he will bit them and try to chew on their hand. It was a cute thing for awhile but it's starting to actually hurt and break skin. How can I train him to stop biting people? Is there anything else I can do besides chew toys that can help him?

Comment: Please also read this answer on [bite inhibition](http://pets.stackexchange.com/a/10125/47) and the link therein. Teaching bite inhibition is probably the most important skill to teach your puppy.

Comment: Get some gloves.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When he nips, shout "ow! no!" a bit louder and sooner than necessary, and if necessary stop playing and walk away. That's how dogs teach each other not to nip, after all -- they growl or bark and don't play with the annoying one until he learns not to be so rough.

"Pit bulls" should be as capable of being gentle/careful as any other dog. But a puppy is a baby; as surrogate parent, it's your job to teach him how to be a Good Dog.

Oh -- and give the pup some good chew-toys.

Comment: Definitely good points for the 'ow' and toys. If you only ever tell him off for chewing things and don't give him a chew toy, then it's just frustrating for the pup! There's plenty of chew toys designed specifically for teething too. Treat rewards for playing gentle often help too :)